# How to globally define configuration of Serializer used in API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

In order to user the @MaxDepth annotation in entities, the `enable_max_depth` property has to be set explicitly in serializer context (e.g. in config of the @ApiPlatform annotation), so on entity level, so for each entity

Is there a way to define this property `enable_max_depth=true` for all entities of the project ? Something we could find in `api-platform.yaml` and which will look like that :

```
api-platform:
    serializer:
        enable_max_depth: true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such global option for now (it can be worth adding it, PR welcome).
However, [you can register a `SerializerContextBuilder`](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically) to add this context entry automatically for all resources:

```
<?php
namespace App\Serializer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\SerializerContextBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

final class MaxDepthContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, ?array $extractedAttributes = null): array
    {
        $context = $this->decorated->createFromRequest($request, $normalization, $extractedAttributes);
        $context['enable_max_depth'] = true;

        return $context;
    }
}
```

Then register this new class as a service decorator:

```
# api/config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...
    'App\Serializer\MaxDepthContextBuilder':
        decorates: 'api_platform.serializer.context_builder'
        autoconfigure: false
        autowire: true
```

Comment: Great, will probably create a PR for global config but the service decorator is a clean workaround for me